# Pollinator mating system in orchids

Tags: botany, entomology, behaviour

I came across three terms in an article on pseudocopulation. However I don't quite understand what it means.

They are:

1) solitary and haplodiploid

2) social and haplodiploid

3) diploid

These are mentioned in reference to pollinator mating systems in orchids. Could anyone please explain the above mentioned terms?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article you read so I have context. I assume from the terms that the terms refer to the insect pollinators but I would like to be certain before I answer.

Answer (score 1):

As 3cat already stated, the terms actually refer to the pollinators. While *solitary* and *social* describe the behavioural traits (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitary_bee#Solitary_and_communal_bees) wikipedia article), *diploid* and *haplodiploid* give information about the chromosome number of the pollinators (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploidy#Diploid) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplodiploid)).

The descriptions in the article depict different combinations of both characteristics.